# Linux VMware Workstation, How to delete VM

Tags: linux, vmware, vmware-workstation

There are many "How to delete VM" articles but I found none works for VMware Workstation under Linux.

I checked its online user manual --
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-0EE752F8-C159-487A-9159-FE1F646EE4CA.html

But didn't find article on delete VM. So how to delete an existing VM under VMware Workstation under Linux (Pro 15.0)?

Comment: You mean it doesn't work because at the end of the instructions the vm is still there or because it's not possible to follow the instructions?

Comment: With VM Player, a simple `rm -rf` does the job, though It's a good idea to shut down and not suspend. You can also use "remove from library" and select "remove from disc" in the GUI.

Comment: It's not possible to follow the instructions, @Ronaldo, as I can't find those menus under VMware Workstation under Linux.

Comment: thanks @AFH, I know `rm -rf` would work, but am looking for a more canonical way. where can I find the "remove from library" and select "remove from disc" in the GUI?  I looked again, but still can't see them.

Comment: It's in the context menu of the VM in the main window, at least it is in VM Player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With VMware Workstation (Pro), you can open the VM, from the menu, choose VM > Manage > Delete from Disk.

Alternatively, show the Library, right click on the VM to show a context menu, and choose Manage > Delete from Disk.

If all else fails, you can simply delete the VM's directory (assuming that you don't have any important files in it that aren't directly tied to the VM).

Comment: @xpt Oops, corrected.

Comment: great, thx a lot